# CORS - How can I enable a series of ports (.Net Core 3.1)

Tags: cors, port, wildcard, asp.net-core-3.1

How can I allow a series of ports for a certain site in one statement?

This is my code and would like to place all five in one smarter statement.

can anyone help?

```
options.AddPolicy("SecurePolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080",
                                        "http://localhost:8081",
                                        "http://localhost:8082",
                                        "http://localhost:8083",
                                        "http://localhost:8084")
                        .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension method on the `CorsPolicyBuilder` that will generate these URLs for you:

```cs
public static CorsPolicyBuilder WithOrigins(this CorsPolicyBuilder builder, string base, params int[] ports)
{
    return builder.WithOrigins(ports.Select(p => $"{base}:{p}").ToArray());
}
```

You could then use that like this:

```cs
options.AddPolicy("SecurePolicy", builder => builder
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost", 8080, 8081, 8082, 8083, 8084)
    .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod());
```

Alternatively, you could also just pass in the first and the last port and have the extension method loop over the ports.

Comment: Thanks for that.
Shouldn't it be
`return builder.WithOrigins(ports.Select(port => $"{base}:{port}").ToArray());` ?